# How to group values in pandas by quartiles and get metrics of other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas DataFrame. I want to calculate sum and average of 2 other columns, based on a value condition in the 1st column, and get results for each group (sum, average) and number of examples in each group.

```py
 
#    quartile  value1   value2
#    1         1        0.9                   
#    1         1        0.8                   
#    2         1        0.75                   
#    2         0        0.75                   
#    3         0        0.5                  
#    3         0        0.4 
#    3         1        0.3                   
#    4         0        0.1
```

My desired output should look like:

```py
#    quartile  value1_sum   value2_avg  no_of_instances_in_val1
#    1         2            0.85        2          
#    2         1            0.75        2           
#    3         1            0.40        3          
#    4         0            0.10        1
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"quartile" : [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4], "value1" : [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], "value2" : [0.9, 0.8, 0.75, 0.75, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1]})
```

You can aggregate it in the following way:

```
data.groupby("quartile").agg({"value1" : sum, "value2" : mean, "quartile" : len})
```

You will then simply have to rename the columns as you desire.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To adhere to your desired output better, we can use [named aggregation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation), as follows:

```
(df.groupby('quartile', as_index=False)
   .agg(value1_sum=('value1', 'sum'), 
        value2_avg=('value2', 'mean'), 
        no_of_instances_in_val1=('value1', 'size'))
)
```

**Output**

```
   quartile  value1_sum  value2_avg  no_of_instances_in_val1
0         1           2        0.85                        2
1         2           1        0.75                        2
2         3           1        0.40                        3
3         4           0        0.10                        1
```